# Windows 10 Technical Preview: running custom commands

Tags: windows, unix, cygwin, windows-10-preview

I have recently installed the Windows 10 Technical Preview and like using unix in my terminal. When I had Windows 8 I used a very lightweight application called gow that installed a few unix commands into my Windows terminal. I installed this tool on Windows 10 and for some reason the Unix commands will only work from the bin folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\gow . I have also tried installing Cygwin and it never works on Windows 8 or Windows 10. Help!
Thanks

UPDATE: Ramhound's solution worked! Thanks :)

Comment: @Ramhound Please copy the answer to the "Your Answer" form, for it to be marked as solved by the OP.

Comment: @Ramhound if boatofturtles does it, he/she is going to wait 2 days before picking his/her own answer.

Comment: @screener - Feel free to do it then.  I don't need the reputation.

Comment: sorry guys I posted it just now